# How to choose personal credit card instead of family credit card for app purchase?

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore, accounts, family-sharing

I have an Apple account and I'm on a share plan with my family, as we share Apple Music. I want to make app purchases, but I want to buy apps on my own, with my own credit card.

Is this possible? Or do I need 2 devices with 2 separate Apple IDs?

Comment: Please search before asking questions. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257130

Comment: There is a workaround not mentioned at the linked question.. If you redeem an iTunes gift card on your individual account the balance of that is used before the family organizers credit card.

Comment: @tubedogg the correct way to deal with this is to mark this question as a duplicate of your link - but I can't as the other answer is not upvoted and although I see it is a dup I don't know if the answer is true

Comment: @Mark Yes I'm aware of how to flag dupes. As you note, though, you cannot do so unless there is at least one upvoted answer on the prior question.

Comment: @Tyson In that case, trying to purchase would still trigger Ask to Buy if it's set, but then use the GC after it's approved? Or are you saying that a GC balance overrides everything?

Comment: I was hoping someone would know if the answer was correct and up vote it :(

Comment: @Mark Ah, okay, sorry. I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @tubedogg it should, but to be honest I don't know, we don't have anyone with "ask to buy".  We do use gift cards tho to split up spending so that everyone is deciding to spend their own money instead if the organizers.

Comment: @tubedogg the [family sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088) page indicates the organizers card is charged which has been a giant complaint about how family sharing works, it would be nice if they changed that.  The only work around I've know of is usage of iTunes gift cards.  If you find out differently we would love to know it.

Comment: @Tyson Yeah I removed my comment because I think the person who purchased last night actually had some credit on his account, which would've been used first. I haven't found out for sure yet. Might try buying something on the other person's account and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If Purchase Sharing is enabled in the Family Sharing options, it will indeed charge the organizer when a family member makes a purchase. If Purchase Sharing is disabled, each account will be charged for their own purchases. I understand initially they were bundled together but it’s now possible to enable Family Sharing without sharing purchases.